# Unable to start a node

Tags: chainlink

I am trying to run a chainlink node on rinkeby. The logs do not indicate an error, but the container exits code 137. I've tried versions 0.10.7 and 0.10.6. My db is postgres:13.1.

Any thoughts on what I'm missing? (SO is asking me to provide more details, but I feel like I've already provided the relevant details?)

### /etc/default/chainlink

```
ETH_PROJECT_NETWORK="rinkeby"
ROOT=/chainlink
LOG_LEVEL=debug
ETH_CHAIN_ID=4
MIN_OUTGOING_CONFIRMATIONS=2
LINK_CONTRACT_ADDRESS=0x01BE23585060835E02B77ef475b0Cc51aA1e0709
GAS_UPDATER_ENABLED=true
ALLOW_ORIGINS=*
TLS_CERT_PATH=/chainlink/tls/server.crt
TLS_KEY_PATH=/chainlink/tls/server.key
```

### Docker

```
docker create -ti --name chainlink-rinkeby \
--net chainlink-rinkeby-net \
--link chainlink-rinkeby-pg:chainlink-pg \
-e ETH_URL=wss://:SECRET@rinkeby.infura.io/wss/v3/ID \
-e 'DATABASE_URL=postgresql://postgres:PW@chainlink-pg:5432/postgres' \
--env-file=/etc/default/chainlink \
-v chainlink-rinkeby-data:/chainlink \
-v /etc/chainlink/tls:/chainlink/tls \
-p 6689:6689 \
smartcontract/chainlink:0.10.7 local n -p /chainlink/password -a /chainlink/api
```

#### VOLUME CONTENTS

```
# ls -lR /chainlink
/chainlink:
total 52
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    55 Jun  5 19:44 api
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 13643 Jun  5 19:44 log.jsonl
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    36 Jun  5 19:44 password
drwx------. 2 root root  4096 Jun  5 19:44 tempkeys
drwx------. 2   70 root  4096 Jun  4 20:20 tls

/chainlink/tempkeys:
total 0

/chainlink/tls:
total 16
-rw-------. 1 999 root 1094 Jun  4 20:20 server.crt
-rw-------. 1 999 root 1704 Jun  4 20:20 server.key
```

### LOGS

```
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Starting Chainlink Node 0.10.7 at commit 6604a647da8af2e0daafb652af13a420b7128f9c cmd/local_client.go:56  InstanceUUID=6fd0d4c6-d290-47fc-b400-09909ca38591 SHA=6604a647da8af2e0daafb652af13a420b7128f9c Version=0.10.7 id=boot
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Query executed                                     postgres@v1.0.8/migrator.go:183 elapsed=1.089297 sql=SELECT count(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = CURRENT_SCHEMA() AND table_name = 'migrations' AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Query executed                                     postgres/transaction.go:36 elapsed=0.179061 rows=0 sql=SET LOCAL lock_timeout = 15000; SET LOCAL idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 3600000;
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Query executed                                     migrations/migration_helper.go:379 elapsed=0.645549 rows=1 sql=SELECT count(1) FROM "migrations" WHERE id = '1611847145'
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Query executed                                     postgres/transaction.go:36 elapsed=0.213993 rows=0 sql=SET LOCAL lock_timeout = 15000; SET LOCAL idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 3600000;
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Query executed                                     migrations/migration_helper.go:379 elapsed=0.480537 rows=1 sql=SELECT count(1) FROM "migrations" WHERE id = '0002_gormv2'
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Query executed                                     postgres/transaction.go:36 elapsed=0.159084 rows=0 sql=SET LOCAL lock_timeout = 15000; SET LOCAL idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 3600000;
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Query executed                                     migrations/migration_helper.go:379 elapsed=0.432966 rows=1 sql=SELECT count(1) FROM "migrations" WHERE id = '0003_eth_logs_table'
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Query executed                                     postgres/transaction.go:36 elapsed=0.202275 rows=0 sql=SET LOCAL lock_timeout = 15000; SET LOCAL idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 3600000;
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Query executed                                     migrations/migration_helper.go:379 elapsed=0.294391 rows=1 sql=SELECT count(1) FROM "migrations" WHERE id = '0004_cleanup_tx_state'
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Query executed                                     postgres/transaction.go:36 elapsed=0.131926 rows=0 sql=SET LOCAL lock_timeout = 15000; SET LOCAL idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 3600000;
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Query executed                                     migrations/migration_helper.go:379 elapsed=0.416135 rows=1 sql=SELECT count(1) FROM "migrations" WHERE id = '0005_eth_tx_attempts_insufficient_eth_index'
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Query executed                                     postgres/transaction.go:36 elapsed=0.187948 rows=0 sql=SET LOCAL lock_timeout = 15000; SET LOCAL idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 3600000;
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Query executed                                     migrations/migration_helper.go:379 elapsed=0.376759 rows=1 sql=SELECT count(1) FROM "migrations" WHERE id = '0006_unique_task_specs_per_pipeline_run'
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Query executed                                     postgres/transaction.go:36 elapsed=0.110912 rows=0 sql=SET LOCAL lock_timeout = 15000; SET LOCAL idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 3600000;
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Query executed                                     migrations/migration_helper.go:379 elapsed=0.298012 rows=1 sql=SELECT count(1) FROM "migrations" WHERE id = '0007_reverse_eth_logs_table'
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Query executed                                     postgres/transaction.go:36 elapsed=0.156825 rows=0 sql=SET LOCAL lock_timeout = 15000; SET LOCAL idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 3600000;
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Query executed                                     migrations/migration_helper.go:379 elapsed=0.293494 rows=1 sql=SELECT count(1) FROM "migrations" WHERE id = '0008_reapply_eth_logs_table'
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Query executed                                     postgres/transaction.go:36 elapsed=0.141752 rows=0 sql=SET LOCAL lock_timeout = 15000; SET LOCAL idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 3600000;
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Query executed                                     migrations/migration_helper.go:379 elapsed=0.258758 rows=1 sql=SELECT count(1) FROM "migrations" WHERE id = '0009_add_min_payment_to_flux_monitor_spec'
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Query executed                                     postgres/transaction.go:36 elapsed=0.119545 rows=0 sql=SET LOCAL lock_timeout = 15000; SET LOCAL idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 3600000;
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Query executed                                     migrations/migration_helper.go:379 elapsed=0.205955 rows=1 sql=SELECT count(1) FROM "migrations" WHERE id = '0010_bridge_fk'
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Query executed                                     postgres/transaction.go:36 elapsed=0.106754 rows=0 sql=SET LOCAL lock_timeout = 15000; SET LOCAL idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 3600000;
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Query executed                                     migrations/migration_helper.go:379 elapsed=0.296148 rows=1 sql=SELECT count(1) FROM "migrations" WHERE id = '0011_latest_round_requested'
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Query executed                                     postgres/transaction.go:36 elapsed=0.134713 rows=0 sql=SET LOCAL lock_timeout = 15000; SET LOCAL idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 3600000;
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Query executed                                     migrations/migration_helper.go:379 elapsed=0.29082 rows=1 sql=SELECT count(1) FROM "migrations" WHERE id = '0012_change_jobs_to_numeric'
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Query executed                                     postgres/transaction.go:36 elapsed=0.123554 rows=0 sql=SET LOCAL lock_timeout = 15000; SET LOCAL idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 3600000;
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Query executed                                     migrations/migration_helper.go:379 elapsed=0.333736 rows=1 sql=SELECT count(1) FROM "migrations" WHERE id = '0013_create_flux_monitor_round_stats_v2'
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Query executed                                     postgres/transaction.go:36 elapsed=0.131023 rows=0 sql=SET LOCAL lock_timeout = 15000; SET LOCAL idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 3600000;
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Query executed                                     migrations/migration_helper.go:379 elapsed=0.30217 rows=1 sql=SELECT count(1) FROM "migrations" WHERE id = '0014_add_keeper_tables'
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Query executed                                     postgres/transaction.go:36 elapsed=0.165207 rows=0 sql=SET LOCAL lock_timeout = 15000; SET LOCAL idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 3600000;
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Query executed                                     migrations/migration_helper.go:379 elapsed=0.355864 rows=1 sql=SELECT count(1) FROM "migrations" WHERE id = '0015_simplify_log_broadcaster'
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Query executed                                     postgres/transaction.go:36 elapsed=0.117584 rows=0 sql=SET LOCAL lock_timeout = 15000; SET LOCAL idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 3600000;
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Query executed                                     migrations/migration_helper.go:379 elapsed=0.375725 rows=1 sql=SELECT count(1) FROM "migrations" WHERE id = '0016_pipeline_task_run_dot_id'
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Query executed                                     postgres/transaction.go:36 elapsed=0.13459 rows=0 sql=SET LOCAL lock_timeout = 15000; SET LOCAL idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 3600000;
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Query executed                                     migrations/migration_helper.go:379 elapsed=0.226877 rows=1 sql=SELECT count(1) FROM "migrations" WHERE id = '0017_bptxm_chain_nonce_fastforward'
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Query executed                                     postgres/transaction.go:36 elapsed=0.134527 rows=0 sql=SET LOCAL lock_timeout = 15000; SET LOCAL idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 3600000;
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Query executed                                     migrations/migration_helper.go:379 elapsed=0.202029 rows=1 sql=SELECT count(1) FROM "migrations" WHERE id = '0018_add_node_version_table'
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Query executed                                     postgres/transaction.go:36 elapsed=0.103125 rows=0 sql=SET LOCAL lock_timeout = 15000; SET LOCAL idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 3600000;
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Query executed                                     migrations/migration_helper.go:379 elapsed=0.2148 rows=1 sql=SELECT count(1) FROM "migrations" WHERE id = '0019_last_run_height_column_to_keeper_table'
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Query executed                                     postgres/transaction.go:36 elapsed=0.102051 rows=0 sql=SET LOCAL lock_timeout = 15000; SET LOCAL idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 3600000;
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Query executed                                     migrations/migration_helper.go:379 elapsed=0.196686 rows=1 sql=SELECT count(1) FROM "migrations" WHERE id = '0020_remove_result_task'
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Query executed                                     postgres/transaction.go:36 elapsed=0.132126 rows=0 sql=SET LOCAL lock_timeout = 15000; SET LOCAL idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 3600000;
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Query executed                                     migrations/migration_helper.go:379 elapsed=0.246 rows=1 sql=SELECT count(1) FROM "migrations" WHERE id = '0021_add_job_id_topic_filter'
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Query executed                                     postgres/transaction.go:36 elapsed=0.139077 rows=0 sql=SET LOCAL lock_timeout = 15000; SET LOCAL idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 3600000;
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Query executed                                     migrations/migration_helper.go:379 elapsed=0.274465 rows=1 sql=SELECT count(1) FROM "migrations" WHERE id = '0022_unfinished_pipeline_task_run_idx'
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Query executed                                     postgres/transaction.go:36 elapsed=0.121325 rows=0 sql=SET LOCAL lock_timeout = 15000; SET LOCAL idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 3600000;
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Query executed                                     migrations/migration_helper.go:379 elapsed=0.312579 rows=1 sql=SELECT count(1) FROM "migrations" WHERE id = '0023_add_confirmations_to_direct_request'
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Query executed                                     postgres/transaction.go:36 elapsed=0.186759 rows=0 sql=SET LOCAL lock_timeout = 15000; SET LOCAL idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 3600000;
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Query executed                                     migrations/migration_helper.go:379 elapsed=0.38175 rows=1 sql=SELECT count(1) FROM "migrations" WHERE id = '0024_add_cron_spec_tables'
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Query executed                                     postgres/transaction.go:36 elapsed=0.162392 rows=0 sql=SET LOCAL lock_timeout = 15000; SET LOCAL idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 3600000;
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Query executed                                     migrations/migration_helper.go:379 elapsed=0.311613 rows=1 sql=SELECT count(1) FROM "migrations" WHERE id = '0025_create_log_config_table'
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Query executed                                     postgres/transaction.go:36 elapsed=0.154727 rows=0 sql=SET LOCAL lock_timeout = 15000; SET LOCAL idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 3600000;
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Query executed                                     migrations/migration_helper.go:379 elapsed=0.39014 rows=1 sql=SELECT count(1) FROM "migrations" WHERE id = '0026_eth_tx_meta'
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Query executed                                     postgres/transaction.go:36 elapsed=0.105127 rows=0 sql=SET LOCAL lock_timeout = 15000; SET LOCAL idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 3600000;
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Query executed                                     migrations/migration_helper.go:379 elapsed=0.285599 rows=1 sql=SELECT count(1) FROM "migrations" WHERE id = '0027_cascade_ocr_latest_round_request'
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Query executed                                     postgres/transaction.go:36 elapsed=0.143165 rows=0 sql=SET LOCAL lock_timeout = 15000; SET LOCAL idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 3600000;
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  Query executed                                     orm/orm.go:162          elapsed=3.02465 rows=0 sql=INSERT INTO "node_versions" ("version","created_at") VALUES ('0.10.7','2021-06-05 19:44:27.6') ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [DEBUG] GasUpdater: dynamic gas updates are enabled        chainlink/application.go:165 ethGasPriceDefault=20000000000
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [INFO]  DatabaseBackup: periodic database backups are disabled chainlink/application.go:179
2021-06-05T19:44:27Z [DEBUG] Off-chain reporting disabled                       chainlink/application.go:281
There are no accounts, creating a new account with the specified password
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the process was OOM'd
The server didn't have enough ram